# Oracle String Aggregation using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am currently using ROW_NUMBER() with Order by clause to generate a sequence number (seq_num) for filtering purpose.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
   OVER (
      ORDER BY A.CARMODEL)
      AS seq_num,
   'A' AS SALES_CATEGORY,
   '1000' AS SALES_TARGET
```

If I would like to have a predefined list of CARMODEL to be of a higher priority in terms of seq_num, is that possible? How should I achieve it?

For instance:

```
1   A   CAR1    1000
2   A   CAR2    1000
3   A   CAR3    1000
4   A   CAR4    1000
5   A   CAR5    1000
6   A   CAR6    1000
```

I will need CAR1 and CAR2 to always be on top (seq_num=1 and seq_num=2) in terms of seq_num (higher pirority) and the rest will then following the seq_num 3,4,5,6 and onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case expression to influence the ordering, here is an example:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY
                         case when A.CARMODEL IN('car1','car2') then 1 else 2 end
                       , A.CARMODEL)
    AS seq_num
  , 'A'    AS SALES_CATEGORY
  , '1000' AS SALES_TARGET
FROM x
```

or:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY
                         case when A.CARMODEL = 'car1' then 1
                                   A.CARMODEL = 'car2' then 2
                              else 3 end
                       , A.CARMODEL)
    AS seq_num
  , 'A'    AS SALES_CATEGORY
  , '1000' AS SALES_TARGET
FROM x
```